# Troubleshoot PHP MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run this query:

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO `Validation` (`Key`, `Status`, `Notes`, `Serial`) VALUES (max(Key)+1, 'Valid', '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."', '0')";
```

through my PHP script, but each time it displays this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key)+1, 'Valid', 'USER', '0')' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate an ID that increments automatically? In that case you can just use AUTO_INCREMENT on the column and it will do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use Key there. One way round this would be to do a SELECT statement before the INSERT to find out the max(Key) value. Another (preferable) way would be to make the database auto increment the KEY column

Comment: I attempted to add the auto increment to the column, but Ikeep gtting this error: #1063 - Incorrect column specifier for column 'Key'

Comment: What type of column is Key? It should be one of (TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER, or BIGINT) for auto increment to work

Answer (score 4):

`KEY` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), so if you've picked it as a column name, you *must* quote it (with backticks) *every* time:

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO `Validation` (`Key`, `Status`, `Notes`, `Serial`) 
    VALUES (
        max(`Key`) + 1, 
        'Valid', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
        , '0'
    )";
```

Note that you don't *have* to quote non-reserved words with backticks.

I'm not actually sure that this will work -- doesn't MySQL prohibit reading from the same table that you're updating in a single query still?  Regardless, as mentioned in the comments, it looks like you're just replicating by hand [what `AUTO_INCREMENT` does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) for you automatically.  Consider using it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery.

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO `Validation` (`Key`, `Status`, `Notes`, `Serial`) VALUES ((SELECT max(Key) FROM Validation)+1, 'Valid', '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."', '0')";
```